# Homestead and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web

I'm looking for some assistance. I'd like to use PHP to build a web-based health system. Laravel is something I'm familiar with. I'm still confused about the difference between homestead and Laravel. Could someone please explain and advise me on which one to use? Thank you.

Comment: Homestead isn't something you use _instead of_ Laravel; it's something you use _to work on_ Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Homestead is a vagrant box configured specifically configured to locally develop Laravel applications. Laravel is a MVC framework written in php.